# show content after input using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have put display:none to other p tag and div,

how can I show them after entering myname

I want to enter myname and show all the content under display:none div

```html
<form method="post">
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="myname" />
  </p><label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter your names" />
    </label>
</form>
<div style="display:none;">
  <p>enter your age to enter this site</p>
  <p>mr.myname</p>

  <div>
    waiting for your age to enter site </div>
  <input type="text" name="age" />
</div>
```

Comment: Add an `onsubmit` listener to the form that calls `.preventDefault()` on the event (otherwise the page reloads when you submit the form), then changes the style of the div.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you mean something like `$("[name=myname]").on("input",function() { $("#otherstuff").toggle(this.value=="Fred Brown"?"":"none"); })`

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: @brk then why not vote to close it as unclear?

Comment: Btw, showing a succession of input fields (then finally sending all of their data to the server?) is best done using a slightly different approach where you don't have to manually implement every step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
$('form').submit(function(e){
  $('#txtname').text($('[name=myname]').val());
  $('#container').show();
  e.preventDefault();// only for demonstration
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<p>
  <input type="text" name="myname" />
</p
><label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter your names" />
</label>
</form>
<div id="container" style="display:none;">
<p>enter your age to enter this site</p>
<p id="txtname"></p>

<div>
   waiting for your age to enter site  </div>
  <input type="text" name="age" />
</div>
```

Comment: this worked for me. but the problem is that. it only input text and show content. but i want it to be based on form post as in to load page and display hidden content

Comment: @FredBrown, *i want it to be based on form post as in to load page*.....this is not quite clear......the answer above is only to give an idea on how to pass values within elements.......thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your work by using [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) for DOM manipulations and e.g. listen to the [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) of your input to display the content.
With the following example, try typing your name then unfocus the input, you will see the content appear.

```js
$('input[name="myname"]').blur(function() {
  $('div').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post">
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="myname" />
    </p>
    <label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter your names"/>
    </label>
  </form>
  <div style="display:none;">
    <p>enter your age to enter this site</p>
    <p>mr.myname</p>

    <div>
      waiting for your age to enter site
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="age" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// 1. Include jQuery to your code if not yet done
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

// 2. Change this line 
<input type="text" name="age" />
To this
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" />

// 3. Add this code where you wish to print the age
<span id="printAge" style="color:green"></span>

// 4. Give this code before <body> closes
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#age').keyup(function () { 
         var ageText = $(this).val();
         $('#printAge').html();
    });
 });
</script>
```

Don't hesitate to reply if you still find issues @Chris G

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to show the hidden div after the user clicks the submit button. I may be understanding it wrong though so correct me if I am.

First let's give the hidden div a class of "hidden-div" for example.
Then I'll use jQuery to listen for the submit button click using the following code:

```
// grab the element with the class hidden-div
var hiddenDiv = $('.hidden-div');
// create an event listener on the button with type=submit
$('button[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
   // prevent the default action which is submitting the form
    e.preventDefault();

    // show the hidden div
    hiddenDiv.show();
});
```

---

To use jQuery you need to import it; u can do it using a script tag right before the closing `</body>` tag

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```js
$("[name=myname]").on("input",function() { 
  $("#otherstuff").toggle(this.value=="Fred Brown"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="myname" />
  </p><label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter your names" />
    </label>
</form>
<div id="otherstuff" style="display:none;">
  <p>enter your age to enter this site</p>
  <p>mr.myname</p>

  <div>
    waiting for your age to enter site </div>
  <input type="text" name="age" />
</div>
```